# How can I run Linux commands on an Android device?

Tags: android, shell, adb

On some Android devices, in the ADB shell, I can only run `echo`, `cd`, `ls`. When I run:

```
tar -cvf //mnt/sdcard/BackUp1669/apk/test.tar /mnt/sdcard/test.apk
```

Or the command `cp`, it returns:

```
sh: tar: not found
```

Why can I not run these commands? Some devices support these commands. My end goal is to copy a file from the */data/data* folder to SD card. I got *su* and I got the following code:

```
int timeout = 1000;
String command = "tar -cvf /" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/cp/"
        + packageName + ".tar" + " " + path;
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(
        process.getInputStream())), 64);

String inLine;
try {
    StringBuilder sbCommand = new StringBuilder();
    sbCommand.append(command).append(" ");
    sbCommand.append("\n");
    os.writeBytes(command.toString());
    if (is != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++) {
            if (is.ready())
                break;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (is.ready()) {
            inLine = is.readLine();
        } else {
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It always stops in `is.ready()`, and when I changed it to `process.waitfor()` it also stopped. Why?

Comment: You do realize, that the android shell is far more restricted than a standard Linux os right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run Linux commands on Android. But there are usually just very few pre-installed.
If you want to add more commands you might want to [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29) your device and install [busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.busybox.installer) on it.

This is not for productive use within an application but can help you to work with your device.

Comment: Thanks, I know where the problem is. But my problem still not been resolved.

Comment: So how can I run `locate` command on Android for searching files?  It seems this is not an applet in BusyBox.

Answer (score 13):

As far as i know, the only way to run shell commands is:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the binaries for your system, you can run anything on your system.

Saying that you have to understand that you have to find the binaries for `tar`.

Look here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=872438

And possibly other places..

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get this done by using a Terminal Emulator app. As you wrote above, I don't know how well DOS commands will work. But, a Terminal Emulator works without root.

Comment: You should provide more context to your answer. If you do not provide much context then give the questioner a suggestion in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Termux app on your android device and run Linux command by using that app

Answer (score -1):

Install busybox, then type the command in the following format:

busybox [linux command]

You cannot use all the linux commands without busybox, because Android doesn't have all the binaries that are available in a standard linux operating system.

FYI, a binary is just a file that contains compiled code. A lot of the default binaries are stored in /system/bin/sh directory. All these commands like 'cp' 'ls' 'get' etc, are actually binaries. You can view them through:

ls -a /system/bin/sh

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

In reply to  **Igor Ganapolsky**, You would have to have a database set up for locate.

Probably `find` would be adequate for your needs.

example:

```
find -name *.apk
```