# How to run a shell script in android app?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have one shell script placed in /sdcard/test.sh
And the test.sh file has the below command.
`screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/sreee.mp4`

When I run this command from adb shell command from Windows machine command executed successfully without any errors.

My Question is how can I execute the same script from Android app where When I press the start button?

Could you please help me out on this with a best example?

Comment: Have you tried [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277822/119114)?

Comment: You will need root access since the uid:gid of `/system/bin/screenrecord` is root:shell. Try out https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser or https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

Comment: I tried Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/sreee.mp4");   Eventhough It is not working :(