# How to use unix command 'cat' in android to concatenate two video files from sd card?

Tags: android, bash, unix, video

I have split a video file into two files 'part1' and 'part2' via Git bash. Both these files are individually unreadable. Now I need to concatenate these two files and then play the video. This works just fine via git bash but since I am very new to android, I can't seem to do it programmatically. 
I did come across an answer here which said to do something like this :

`String[] command = {"ls","-al"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File(/ngs/app/abc));
p = builder.start();`

However, I don't know how to write the command 'cat part1 part2 > new.mp4' using this technique. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: see this it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277709/how-can-run-linux-command-on-android

Comment: @VishalThakkar Yes, but the point is, how do I include the two file names(to be read from the sd card) in the String? How is that going to work?

Answer (score 2):

You have to invoke a shell and pass it the command line as script parameter. For example with the bash shell you would run the following

```
bash -c 'cat part1 part2 > new.mp4'
```

Given your template this would work out as following

```
String[] command = {"bash", "-c", "cat part1 part2 > new.mp4"};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File(/ngs/app/abc));
p = builder.start();
```

Of course `cat` simply con**cat**enates byte streams, hence the name. It's trivial to program smething like that yourself. Pseudocode (actually valid Python)

```
filnew = open("new.mp4", "wb")
fil1 = open("part1", "rb")
fil2 = open("part1", "rb")
filnew.write( fil1.read() )
filnew.write( fil2.read() )
filnew.close()
fil1.close()
fil2.close()
```

Comment: Except it's not quite *that* trivial. The pseudocode here reads the entirety of part1 into memory before writing it out, which for a large video on a mobile device, could cause the app to crash due to lack of memory. `cat` uses streaming, and so should an app that concatenates large files.